# Отладчик на python

Tags: python

Посоветуйте. Нужен удобный отладчик и трассировщик на python. pdb, winpdb не предлагать.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант — [pudb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb).

Попробуйте посмотреть [PythonDebuggers на wiki.python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggers), там довольно большой список. Возможно, подберете что-нибудь по вкусу.

Answer (score 0):

Советую обратить внимание на Wing IDE. Очень удобная штука для питонера. Она, правда, платная, но мы же в россии :)

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю, сам пользуюсь pudb, отличный инструмент. Там где его нет и не хочется устанавливать (например сервера и т.п.), использую pdb.

Года 3 назад писал статью о нём http://adw0rd.com/2012/3/24/python-django-pudb/ , думаю пригодится тем кто пришел в эту тему. Про pdb тоже есть http://adw0rd.com/2012/10/7/python-pdb/

Answer (score 0):

Ну если прям удобный то используйте отладчик из PyCharm. Удобней некуда :)